# Which data structure should I use for implementing a code indexer

Tags: database-design, source-code, indexing

I need to write a basic code indexer, which needs to be fast. Should I use an embedded SQLite database for this or should rather rely on a custom data structure, or even flat files as used by ctags?

Some of my requirements:

- Find all references of a variable.
- Go to function implementation
- etc...

Any pointers to docs explaining the theory behind code indexing (and the relevant data structures would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: I'd imagine you'd need quite a few different data structures here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use something remotely reasonable for the data structure, the limiting factor on your speed will typically be reading and parsing the source code.

While SQLite can undoubtedly work, in this case you probably have a fairly small number of pre-designed "queries" to support, so using SQL doesn't really gain you much. I'd at least consider something like [LMDB](https://symas.com/lmdb/) or [RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org/). These will probably do everything you need, and they're extremely fast and light.